# how can I download Blender 2.75 RC for mac?

Tags: installation, osx

I am a Mac user and I am trying to download the latest version of blender that is out, which is Blender 2.75 RC which can be downloaded here:  http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.75
But for some reason when I try to download this file: blender-2.75-rc2-OSX_10.6-x86_64.zip which is for OS X, a web page displaying 403 - Forbidden. One strange thing that I noticed was that I can download the files for Linux and window on my mac, but I get "403 - Forbidden" when I try and download the files of OS X when I'm running OS X?
I researched and some options others suggested. Those being deleting my web history, website data, and cookies. None of that helped.

How do I download Blender 2.75 RC on my iMac when I get the 403 - Forbidden message?

Comment: I'm on windows, but I can download the mac files now.

Comment: I would vote to close this as off topic, but I already accidentally voted for too broad, but oh well. The reason behind this, is because your question isn't about Blender, it's about the blender.org website. BSE only deals with questions regarding how to use Blender, and depending on the question, how to use software in conjunction with Blender. Instead, try reporting your issue to web mailing list, since I don't believe there is a bug reporter for the web site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a temporary problem with the blender website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the same on my mac, but I don't think it's a mac issue, I think it's a web server issue on the blender.org site.

You can download a 2.75 pre-release build for OSX here as well:

https://builder.blender.org/download/